# Modify select data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, group-concat

Its my query join table :

```
SKU | Atributes | Atributes_Value
123 | Color     | Black
123 | Size      | 40
```

can i modify the select query like this ? (below)

```
SKU | new_atributes_value
123 | Black 40
```

i just want to see data with same SKU in one row! i tried distinct but i didn't get the desired result (below)

```
SKU | Atributes | Atributes_Value
123 | Color     | Black
```

my question is where the size 40 ? i want to see that item with sku 123 have a black color and size 40 in one row.. anyone can help me? i need the data for my eCommerce website

Comment: post your query code please.

Comment: you can use group_concat function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..........

```
SELECT sku, group_concat(Atributes_Value separator ' ') as attr_val from table_name group by sku
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the group_concat in mysql:

```
SELECT SKU, GROUP_CONCAT(Atributes_Value SEPARATOR ' ') FROM table GROUP BY SKU;
```